# How to click a particular object using TestComplete without using co-ordinates

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I am using VB scripting language to automate using TestComplete. The script records using co-ordinates of an object, so the script fails if it is run on some other machine. If I don't specify any co-ordinate then it randomly clicks any of the buttons on that page. Please let me know how to click a button without using the co-ordinates?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You want to read http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29935/

Comment: We need something to refer to then it'll be better to help...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click a button without coordinates, the best way is to send keystrokes,

So: either send the "spacebar" keystroke, or send the shortcut keystroke "Alt-X" (or similar)

Comment: The best way is to just have the button clicked (although I like shortcuts also) because not every button has a shortcut. You might want to map the button using NameMapping before to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove coordinates from the Click action in your test, TestComplete will click the center point of the corresponding control. If TestComplete clicks a random object in your case then you call the Click method of a wrong object. Find the correct button object using the [Object Spy](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/28916/) and call the Click or ClickButton method of this object.

Answer (score 0):

get the name of the object using the object spy and use the .CLICK method and the object will be clicked in the center. 
if you do not want to have click item then you can try and create a custom function to select a item in case of combo boxes .clickCell in case of grid etc.